# How to set different colors for text within a single Chakra heading element

Tags: html, css, typescript, frontend, chakra-ui

I am currently building a website with Chakra UI and Typescript. The last word of the main heading is to be a different color than the rest of the heading. For example, in the following snippet, C should be a different color than A and B.

```
<Heading as='h1' color='white'>A B C</Heading>
```

I have tried to solve this several ways, including having multiple header elements and aligning them horizontally with flex. However, I found responsiveness issues and other problems with this method.

```
<Box display='flex'>
    <Heading as='h1' color='white'>A B</Heading>
    <Heading as='h1' color='blue.400'>C</Heading>
</Box>
```

What do you guys suggest doing?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used Chakra UI but I have used `<span>` in regular html and it could accomplish this.

So I did a quick search here and found how you can use `<text>` tags like this:
`<Text color='blue.400' as="span"> C </Text>`
This could be a potential solution.  Let me know if it works!

Comment: I ended up nesting two header elements inside each other, setting the inner header as a span. This worked for me. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up nesting two headers, the inner one being set to a span as shown below

`<Heading as='h1' color='white'>A B <Heading as='span' color='blue'>C</Heading> </Heading>`

This worked for me.